# SASS compilation order: function output assigned to variable not compiled in some code

Tags: sass, bourbon

I'm using Bourbon and SASS-flavour Bootstrap. Here's my base SCSS file:

```
@import '../../bower_components/bourbon/dist/_bourbon.scss';
@import 'app/swatches.scss';
@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/lib/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'app/theme.scss';
```

The idea is that I pull in Bourbon first because I intend to use it all over the place, call in `swatches.scss` to set app-wide variables, call in Bootstrap (which uses some of the swatches), and then go about customising my application on top of Bootstrap. `swatches.scss` looks like this:

```
// The brand
$blue          : #0078ae;
$grey-light    : #58595b;
$grey-dark     : #59595e;
$gradient-blue : linear-gradient( #0089ca, #006cb9 );
$gradient-grey : linear-gradient( #e1e2e2 0, #d8d9da 33%, #cecece 33.001%, #b8b8b8 100% );

// Set Bootstrap's variables (map back to our own vars if need be)
$brand-primary            : $blue;
$btn-default-color        : #fff;
$panel-primary-heading-bg : $gradient-blue;
$panel-default-heading-bg : $gradient-grey;

%gradient-blue {
    @include background-image( $gradient-blue );
}
```

Somehow, Bootstrap doesn't receive the compiled output of `$gradient-blue` — it receives the uncompiled string `linear-gradient( #0089ca, #006cb9 )`. Code in `theme.scss` has no problem invoking `$gradient-blue` (or the extension `%gradient-blue`).

I would have expected `$gradient-blue` to compile once and be done. How is this not happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use linear-gradient in syntax:

```
$gradient-blue : @include linear-gradient( #0089ca, #006cb9 );
$gradient-grey : @include linear-gradient( #e1e2e2 0, #d8d9da 33%, #cecece 33.001%, #b8b8b8 100% );
```

because it's a mixin. Look at documentation: http://bourbon.io/docs/#linear-gradient

Comment: It's also available [as a function](http://bourbon.io/docs/#linear-gradient-function), which is how I'm using it here. The mystery is in why it works in some places and not others: if it works at all, I would expect it to be because the function has executed and returned it's computed value to the variable it's assigned to. But then when it's invoked in Bootstrap the function isn't compiled. Weird!